# If view or pure function doesn't cost any gas, would they be abused/free ride?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, gas-limit

So if I understand this correctly, `view` function only read data from ethereum and doesn't mutate any state and `pure` function doesn't even read data and they are intended for cases like `return 1+1;`

If this is the case, would they be abused since they don't cost any gas? Like could I just use them for free computation? What happen if I have a infinite loop in a view or pure function?

**TLDR**: They won't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to add to @Shawn's good answer.

Yes, you can abuse them. But as the `pure` and `view` computations are performed only on your own node you would only hurt your own node. You would not hurt the Ethereum network in any way. If you call the function(s) enough, you might even crash your node but it still wouldn't hurt the network in any way.

Comment: Say if I call my contract via web 3 without my own node, would that affect the network in anyway?

Comment: No, you always have to call *some* node, so only the called node is affected. You can't access the blockchain without an intermediary node.

Comment: Hmm .. Bear with my ignorance. My understanding is that when you use dapp, you access the free node hosted by infura via web3 ?

Comment: Infura is one way, yes. They provide you with a node you can use. But there are many other alternatives.

Comment: So is it fair to say that we could free ride the computation of pure/view function when we are not running our own node? Eg. Could I run expensive number crunch task on one of the network node for free ?

Comment: That's between you and Infura - I have no idea what kind of restrictions / rate limits they have.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So as far as ethereum network is concerned, i can not really free ride computation, as it's only on my "own" node and won't be broadcasted ?

Comment: Please post a new question if you have further questions - discussions in comments is discouraged. But yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 13):

`pure` and `view` functions only are "free" when you call them externally, as in you call that function by itself and run the calculation on your node. So if you had a function that returned "1+1", yes you can call that individual view function as many times as you want for free, even without creating a transaction.

However, if you use a `view` or `pure` function within an internal function which DOES cost gas, you will be charged for those calculations like normal.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is it possible to invoke the bad pure function not using my own node ? Would that still be consider abuse or free ride ? Does the network penalize such behavior in anyway?